# Object is not being cut by Boolean Modifier (Cylinder). How do I make it work

Tags: modifiers

I have a Plane that has been rotated and extruded into a "Square" shape, that I am trying to take an ovular chunk out of with a deformed Cylinder. I have had a multitude of problem with this and have spent the last several hours trying to work out why it won't work. As you can see in the image: It shows me where it should cut, but doesn't cut it. The Edges it has made inside the shape aren't attached to a Vertex and they are intangible. The other problem is obviously the shape hasnt been cut so the faces / edges / vertex are still on the side. I honestly have no clue what to do. and because of this I cant even begin to fix them for the Subsurf mod.
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Are the meshes manifolded and watertight? Have you tried the exact method?

Comment: You've tried changing the mode around between difference/union/intersect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the deformed cylinder wider, and a bit taller, than the other object. Coplanar surfaces don't work so well with boolean operations.

[image]

Or you could avoid booleans and just model that shape using proportional editing.

[image]

Comment: This has solved my problem thank you :)